# Sum the min second even number and max second even number from:

Tags: php, arrays

I am having an list of numbers

9, 48, 2, 1,14, 5, 4, 15, 50, 59, 56, 47

how to find the Sum the min second even number and max second even number:

required output: 4+50 = 54

Note: code also work, if above number position will change or add another number

Comment: Could you show us what's wrong with your attempt, please?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to get us to do your computer science homework for you. Show us that you tried something and what your results are so we know we are helping you not doing the job for you.

Comment: @danielson317  , by helping someone here. you're actually help someone to do there job. What is wrong in my question I don't know.

Comment: The problem with your question is you did not even attempt to solve it yourself. We are here to help you, not to do the work for your.

Answer (score 0):

A bit overkill perhaps, but will do the trick.

```
$numbers = [9, 48, 2, 1,14, 5, 4, 15, 50, 59, 56, 47];

asort($numbers);

$even = array_values(array_filter($numbers, function($i){

    return ($i % 2) == 0;
} ));


$total = $even[1] + $even[count($even) -2];

var_dump($total);
```

Comment: Thank You for the help.